# How to show an array separated by coma no Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am Ultimatley trying to show an array in a container I have made on my html.
However most the help I can find is using jquery for this project I am not allowed to use jquery has anyone got any help this is how far I have gone.

Html
Submit

```
    <label for="yourAnswer">Your Selection:</label>
    <div class="textBox">
      <p id="yourAnswer"></p>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
  var array = []
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked')

  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    array.push(checkboxes[i].value)
  }
  //Below shows array in console for help
 console.log(array)

 const embedElements = () => {
   array.forEach(element => {
   document.getElementById('yourAnswer').innerHTML +=
   `${element}`;
   });
  };
```

Comment: What should your array look like?

Comment: [array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: It should look like this                                       C#, Javascript, C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.from` to turn the `getElementsById` result into an array, and then use `.map(e => e.value)` to extract the values, and then use `.join(', ')` to separate the values with commas and spaces.

```js
const embedElements = () => {
  document.getElementById('yourAnswer').innerHTML = 
     Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked'))
       .map(e => e.value)
       .join(', ');
};
```

```html
<label for="yourAnswer">Your Selection:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkA" value="A" checked><label for="checkA">A</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkB" value="B" ><label for="checkB">B</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkC" value="C" checked><label for="checkC">C</label>
<div class="textBox">
      <p id="yourAnswer"></p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="embedElements()" >Submit</button>
```

Comment: This Kinda works but now what about a space after the coma, also it should work onClick of button an seems to only pick up the array on refreshing of the page. sorry completly fogot to add the button in to the html snippet

Comment: <button type="button" onclick="embedElements()" >Submit</button>

Comment: Those are secondary problems.  But [`array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) takes an argument which is the string to be used as a separator.  you can provide `', '` (comma space) as the separator string.  `array.join(', ')`.  I have edited my answer to do so.

Comment: @joshwebdev, thanks for the feedback.  I've refactored it to work interactively.